# Using an Enum in @BeanParam

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I am using a @BeanParam like this:

```
@GET
public Response listAllPaged(@BeanParam PagedRequest pagedRequest) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

The bean itself:

```
public class PagedRequest {

    @QueryParam("sortOrder")
    @DefaultValue("0")
    public int sortOrder;    
}
```

Now I would like to **change the type of sortOrder** to the following enum:

```
public enum SortOrder {
    ASC("asc"),
    DESC("desc");

    public final String sortOrder;

    SortOrder(String sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }
}
```

But as soon as I do this:

```
public class PagedRequest {

    @QueryParam("sortOrder")
    @DefaultValue("asc")
    public SortOrder sortOrder;
}
```

**My REST Endpoint cannot match the signature anymore and returns a 404**. Why is that? I thought that the presence of a constructor accepting a single String should allow JAX-RS to do the conversion.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I managed to make it work like this, but it does not really answer my initial question...

```
public enum SortOrder {
    ASC,
    DESC;

    public static SortOrder fromString(String param) {
        String toUpper = param.toUpperCase();
        try {
            return valueOf(toUpper);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an int in the path or the enum name?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I am not sure I understand your question. The path has not changed.

Comment: What I mean is something like `/rest/request/ASC` should work where as `/rest/request/1` would not unless you use a `ParamConverter`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It is a query param not a path param, so it is like /rest/request?sortOrder=asc

Comment: This is strange, changing query params shouldn't have any impact on this.

Comment: It should work if you passed "ASC". It's using `Enum.valueOf()`. I could see where there could be an enhancement for converting enum values to upper case. You're welcome to file an issue here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY or just let me know and I can file one.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it that can't be done. It could break anyone not using uppercase enum names. I'll answer with 3 real solutions.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Enum.valueOf(String)` method is used to resolve the value. Since your `SorterOrder` enums are uppercase you'd be required to send the parameter in uppercase.

If you want to pass the value in lowercase only you could change the enum names to lower case, e.g. `SortOrder.asc`.

If you don't know or don't want to care about the case the parameter is sent in you could use a `ParamConverter`.

```java
public class SortOrderParamConverter implements ParamConverter<SortOrder> {
    @Override
    public SortOrder fromString(final String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return SortOrder.valueOf(value.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
        }
        return SortOrder.ASC;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(final SortOrder value) {
        return value.name();
    }
}
```

If you want a more generic approach you could create a `ParamConverter` or all enums.

```java
@Provider
public class EnumParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType, final Type genericType,
                                              final Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (!rawType.isEnum()) {
            return null;
        }
        final Enum<?>[] constants = (Enum<?>[]) rawType.getEnumConstants();
        return new ParamConverter<T>() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public T fromString(final String value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }
                for (Enum<?> e : constants) {
                    if (e.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                        return (T) e;
                    }
                }
                // No match, check toString()
                for (Enum<?> e : constants) {
                    if (e.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                        return (T) e;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(final T value) {
                return value != null ? value.toString() : null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```